# JOptionPane in java x option

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I need help with JOptionPane in Java. When I click OK everything is OK. :) But when I click on x its same like i clicked on OK. How can I solve this. When I click on x I wanna to close app. Here is my code.

```
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        JList choise = new JList(new String[] { "Enter the complaints",
                "View complaints" });
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, choise, "Multi-Select Example",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        if (choise.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
            new ComplaintsApp();
        } else if(choise.getSelectedIndex() == 1 && JOptionPane.OK_OPTION > 0){

            new ComplaintsView();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different JOptionPane, one that returns to the program an indication of which button was pressed: the `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...)`:

```
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JList<String> choice = new JList<>(new String[] {
                "Enter the complaints", "View complaints" });
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                new JScrollPane(choice), "Multi-select Example",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        if (result != JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            // they didn't press OK
            return;
        }
        if (choice.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Complaints App");
        } else if (choice.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
            System.out.println("Complaints View");
        }
    }
}
```